# Perl Getopt::Long Dynamic Parameters

Tags: perl

With GetOpt::Long, is it possible to create a dynamic list of parameters?

myprog.pl --dir /tmp --force --releaes 1.2.3

`my %options = (); 

my @options = qw(dir force release ); 
#note dir and release take argument, and force is a flag
my $result = GetOptions(\%options, \@optons); #or something like that
print "dir $options{dir} \n"; #produces say /tmp
print "force $options{force} \n"; # produces 1 or 0
print "release $options{release} \n"; # and so on`

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible to construct your lists of valid arguments dynamically; all the lists are dynamic, unless you fix them in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
my @options = qw(dir=s force release=s); 
...
my $result = GetOptions(\%options, @options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subs take a list of scalars for arguments. That list can be generated from any expression*, including an array.

```
my @options;
if (condition()) { # Dynamic
   @options = qw( dir=s force release=s );
} else {
   @options = ...;
}

GetOptions(\%options, @optons);
```

* — Prototypes can alter what expressions are allowed and how the expression is evaluated.